# Show quick suggestions, but don't auto-insert them

Tags: visual-studio-code

When typing, how do I still show the word suggestions, but disable the "autocorrect"?

I can add this to the settings:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
}
```

But this disables suggestions altogether. To show what my problem is, let's say that I want to write this: `var example = new Thing();`.

[image]

Comment: Is `Thing()` actually defined and visible to the parser in this file? Or is it outside?

Comment: VS Code doesn't know that it exists, it's defined in another file.

Comment: Yeah, guess that's the problem here then. Could only imagine doing a fake definition if it really bothers you for specific symbols.

Comment: Potential duplicate question and solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083894/409744

Answer (score 1):

While no perfect solution, if you don't want to disable auto-complete and only have this issue with very few symbols, I'd suggest to just defining some dummy object at the beginning of your file:

```
const DummyImports = { Thing, OtherThing };
```

During optimization it would be detected as unused and dropped anyway, but IntelliSense will actually pick it up and offer `Thing` and `OtherThing` as suggestions while typing.